# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 unable to read DVDRW

Tags: mount, dvd, mate

This morning I opened this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769936/cannot-mount-dvd-rw-in-ubuntu-15-04), and it was brought to my attention I was using an oldversion of MATE. I have upgraded to 16.04.
Now, when I try to play the dvd, it spins up the disk, tries very hard to read it, and VLC even gets the disc name displayed on the header bar before it spins down and doesn't read. Any ideas? I'm frazzled.

Thanks again,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading from 15.04 to 16.04 LTS, the libdvdcss package was not installed.

Installed that and DVD works fine.

Seems the errors in 15.04 were rendered obsolete by upgrading.